# WP Query Custom Taxonomy but exclude current term

Tags: php, wordpress

I am setting up a wp_query to list all of the terms in a custom taxonomy. However, I'd like to ammend the code below to exclude the current taxonomy term.

For example, when on the archive.php page for 'term1', I'd like that to be excluded, meaning I am left with 'term2', 'term3' etc.

```
<? 
$args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'topic',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1'
);
?>
<? $tax_menu_items = get_categories( $args );
    foreach ( $tax_menu_items as $tax_menu_item ):?>
        <li>
            <a href="<? echo get_term_link($tax_menu_item,$tax_menu_item->taxonomy); ?>">
                <? echo $tax_menu_item->name; ?>
            </a>
        </li>
    <? endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: In theory if you look at the global $post object that should be the current taxonomy - and from that you can get the id to exclude for your argument. If you need that further explaining let me know :) You can use https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post as a reference.

Comment: Hi @SimonPollard, thnaks for the suggestion. Any chance you could help me to adjust my code above to achieve this? I'm fairly new to wp_query...

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it does depend on where you are using it

```
// Get the category ID
$catID = get_query_var('topic');
// Now run the query excluding the current taxonomy
$args = array(
    'exclude' => $catID,
    'taxonomy' => 'topic',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1'
);
```

Then the rest of your code above. For more on get_categories() take a look at https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories the exclude parameter is definitely what you need - it is just making sure you exclude the correct category ID.

Comment: No luck unfortunately, I'm using the code on the archive.php page, meaning you are already on the page of one of the options displayed via that query?

Comment: HI Simon. Again no luck unfortunately, I should make it clear that I'm using custom taxonomies here, so perhaps the terminology for 'cat' is incorrect?

Comment: Possibly yes... try 'topic' in the get_query_var bit just in case. Ideally we are just looking to find that magical ID then it will all work

Comment: Nope, no luck. We're not trying to exclude 'topic'. 'Topic is the name of the custom taxonomy, whereas my query is displaying the terms within that taxonomy.

Comment: get_query_var('topic') should return the current ID for the topic you are looking at - out of interest how did you create your custom category? need to make sure it is publicly queryable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96165/discussion-between-dungey-140-and-simon-pollard).